# SQL - Filter records of which column's value has multiple combination with another column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a query to filter the records of which column A has more than 1 combination with another column B? I will explain the question in a better way by the example below:

There are 2 tables:

roster

```
staffno | location |   date 
----------------------------
sf001   |    A     | 1/10/2016
sf001   |    A     | 2/10/2016
sf001   |    A     | 3/10/2016
sf002   |    A     | 1/10/2016
sf002   |    B     | 2/10/2016
sf002   |    A     | 3/10/2016
sf003   |    A     | 1/10/2016
sf003   |    A     | 2/10/2016
sf003   |    A     | 3/10/2016
```

staffprofile

```
staffno
-------
sf001
sf002
sf003
sf004
```

I wrote a statement to find the co-existing staff number, and exclude the staff which has more than 1 combination of columns "staffno" and "location". For example, in table "roster", staffno "sf002" has multiple locations "A" and "B", so staffno "sf002" should be excluded in the result; while staffno "sf001" has only 1 single location "A", so this is included.

I wrote following statement:

```
select staffno
from roster a, staffprofile b
where a.staffno = b.staffno
and not exists (
     --some stmt here
)
```

The result should have 2 records: sf001 and sf003.

Originally I wanted to use "NOT EXISTS" to filter those records with multiple combination of fields staffno and location, but I did not know to query those unwanted records. Also I tried to use "Case When", but I fail to write a statement to check those with repeated "staffno" having different "location".

A more advanced query will be finding records with above conditions I described, in addition to having the records within the same month.

Comment: SQL server 2005 onwards does not support your syntax `from table1, table2`. You need to use [explicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: @JohnHC - Even in `SQL SERVER 2016`  comma separated join works. It is just not recommended to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `group by` and `having`:

```
select staffno
from roster
group by staffno
having min(location) = max(location);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT staffno
FROM   staffprofile b
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   roster a
                   WHERE  a.staffno = b.staffno
                   HAVING Count(DISTINCT location) > 0)
```

Inside `sub-query` we are checking the count of `location` for each `staffno` If it is greater than `0` then it will be excluded in `NOT EXISTS`

**Note :** If you don't want same `location` to be duplicated for same `staffno` then remove the `DISTINCT` from `COUNT` aggregate

Comment: I run that statement and it returns sf004 only. I modify last sentence of the sub-query from ">0" to ">1" and it returns "sf001, sf003, and sf004"; and then add additional WHERE clause on the main query to retrieve expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many locations a staff member has like this

```
SELECT staffno,
       COUNT(distinct location)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY staffno
```

Then just take the "1"s

```
SELECT staffno FROM (
  SELECT staffno,
         COUNT(distinct location) as C
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY staffno
) AS sub
WHERE sub.C = 1
```

or use a HAVING

```
SELECT staffno
FROM tablename
GROUP BY staffno
HAVING COUNT(distinct location) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.staffno
from staffprofile t1
inner join 
    (
    select x1.staffno, count(distinct x1.location) loc
    from roster x1
    group by x1.staffno
    having count(distinct x1.location) = 1
    ) t2
  on t1.staffno = t2.staffno
```

Answer (score 0):

to explain this query a little the sub-query aliassed `vu` finds staff that have worked multiple locations (more than 1) in the same year/month

the roster table is then joined to the vu based on StaffNo, year, and month to assure this is restricted to the same month as you mentioned.

then instead of using `NOT EXISTS` the `WHERE vu.StaffNo IS NULL` is restrict results StaffNo who have only worked 1 or less locations in the month.

```
 SELECT roster.StaffNo, Year(roster.Date), Month(roster.Date)
    FROM roster 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Year(date) year, Month(Date) month, StaffNo, COUNT(DISTINCT Location) Locations
        FROM roster
        GROUP BY Year(date), Month(Date), StaffNo
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Location)>1
    ) vu 
        ON roster.StaffNo = vu.StaffNo
        AND Year(roster.Date) = vu.year
        AND Month(roster.Date) = vu.month
    WHERE vu.StaffNo IS NULL
    GROUP BY roster.StaffNo, Year(roster.Date), Month(roster.Date)
```

If you would like to use `NOT EXISTS` syntax you could use the below query

```
SELECT StaffNo, Year(Date), Month(Date)
FROM roster SingleLocationRoster
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Year(date) year, Month(Date) month, StaffNo, COUNT(DISTINCT Location) Locations
    FROM roster
    WHERE SingleLocationRoster.StaffNo = roster.StaffNo
    AND Year(SingleLocationRoster.Date) = Year(roster.Date)
    AND Month(SingleLocationRoster.Date) = Month(roster.Date)
    GROUP BY Year(date), Month(Date), StaffNo
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Location)>1
)
GROUP BY StaffNo, Year(Date), Month(Date)
```